# Eliminate html tags from value (and html decode) using sql server function

Tags: html, sql-server

I want to eliminate Tags from below HTML content using sqlserver functions

```html
select dbo.udf_StripStyle(dbo.udf_StripHTML('<html><head><style type="text/css">.c0 { margin: 0px 0px 10px } </style></head><body><p class="c0">Hi,</p><p class="c0">&#x200b;</p><p class="c0">Test the email details&nbsp;</p><p class="c0">&#x200b;</p></body></html>'))
```

for this i created 2 functions 
**udf_StripStyle** TO remove Styles

```html
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripStyle] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('.c0 {',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('}',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('.c0 {',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('.c0 {',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('}',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('.c0 {',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
```

Another function **udf_StripHTML** to remove HTML Tags

```html
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

when I run this, I get result as `Hi,&#x200b;Test the email details&nbsp;&#x200b;`  and &#x200b values are not getting removed.

But Expected result is `Hi, Test the email details`

Can anyone suggest how to remove &#x200b and show only desired result.

Comment: I suppose my question would be "do you HAVE to do this on the SQL Server side?". Is it maybe possible to do this at the app level before the data is persisted?

Comment: We cant do it from app level so need to do from query level pls let me know of any ideas

Comment: In my experience the word "can't" doesn't really belong in the world of programming. There is nothing stopping you from writing a small c# console app to cursor the rows, strip the html and update the record. Surely the data must enter the db from somewhere. Are you absolutely positive you can't intervene there? If not, I would recommend a powershell script or console app that does what I mentioned above.

Comment: could you use a linked assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing here is a matter of decoding the HTML entities.

TSQL does not offer anything to do this natively. But a quick google search potted me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253101/is-there-any-way-to-do-html-decode-in-sql-server) SO response, which contains a `udf` that should help you.

Alternatively, if you can bring the data outside of SQL Server you could run a simple powershell command to (bluntly) remove the tags and decode the entities:

```
$clean = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($htmlString -replace '<[^>]+>','')
```

Where **$htmlString** is your data from SQL Server.