# Import CSV file with special code µg to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have a `.CSV` file which needs to be imported into a SQL Server table by SSMS.

The file contains `&#181;g` which needs to be imported as "µg".

I use import data function in SSMS.

How to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't do this in T-SQL, if I am honest. It's string manipulation is poor at best.

Comment: There are two obvious choices.  Write code that parses your CSV and replaces the HTML encoding with unicode characters, then load the file.  Or, load the file then update the table you loaded it in to to replace the HTML encoding with unicode characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to do HTML decode in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253101/is-there-any-way-to-do-html-decode-in-sql-server)